# Find an element in array that equals to the sum of the remaining elements

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to think of an efficient algorithm that solves the following problem:

Given an array of integers, return the index of the element in the array that equals to the sum of the remaining elements in the array; if no such element exists, return -1.

For example, given the array of `[1,2,3,6]`, then return 4 since `6=1+2+3;` given `[3, -3, 5, 1]`, return 0 since `3 = -3 + 5 + 1`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Solve this in two runs:

- In the first run create the sum of all integers in the array
- In the second run, check for each element `i`, whether `arrSum == i * 2` holds - equivalent to `arrSum - i == i`. If it holds, you've found your searched element.

In code:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i : arr)
    sum += i;

for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    if(sum == arr[i] * 2)
        return i;

return -1;
```

Runs in `O(n)`.

Comment: I don't get the *2 part. What does that accomplish?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet as explained in the second bullet, that's just another way of saying `arrSum - i == i`, but with the advantage that only a single array-read occurs. Just a little optimization. The `* 2` could be optimized by a bit-shift, but I've ommited that.

Comment: I still don't understand how `arrSum - i` represents "the sum of the remaining elements in the array".

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Pretty simple: the task is to find a value `i` in the array, such that the sum of all elements in the array except for this value  `x` is equal to `i`. Since `arrSum` is the sum of all elements in the array, `arrSum - i` is `x`. One step further would be `arrSum - i = i`. Simplify: `arrSum =  2 * i`.

Comment: ohhhh I was reading "sum of remaining elements" as the sum of the elements starting from `i+1`. Not the sum of all elements excluding that at `i`. I think the use of "remaining" there is really confusing! Though now that I've actually studied the example in the question I can see that your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Although to be honest I'd go with `arrSum - i == i` rather than `arrSum == i * 2` - why obfuscate it? That didn't help! Finally, in the description perhaps use `arrSum - x == x` .. in your description, `i` means value but in your code it means index. (Or instead of `x` just the maximally-clear `arr[i]`?)

Comment: Why not just sum - a[i] == a[i]?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet @shole as for the `arrSum == i * 2`, that's just more efficient, since the array is read only once. If you prefer, you can use `arrSum - x == x` aswell. I've explained that in the answer aswell. As for the rest of the explanation, I've made the meaning of the vars in the explanation pretty clear IMO.

Comment: @Paul: It's not more efficient. It might have been in 1970. But now the compiler/interpreter will certainly optimise it to one read and, even if it didn't, the value is in cache which is super-fast. Meanwhile, you're performing an unnecessary multiplication and seriously obfuscating the code. I don't think that's a good trade-off at all. And yes your explanation is good but I'm critiquing the code that you provided, which is not as clear.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet that's trivial math. I wouldnt consider sth. that trivial an obfuscation. And you can easily optimize further, replacing the multiplication with a shift. And the code should be pretty clear, once you've read the explanation

Comment: @Paul: You're still not getting it. You entirely obfuscate the meaning and intent of the code by using this "trivial math" substitution (which, as explored earlier, holds no technical benefit). That you can derive B from A with simple mathematical axioms doesn't mean anyone reading your code knows that you intended B to start with. It's all well and good having an explanation above it, _but the explanation and the code are not the same thing_. The _code_ is unnecessarily unclear. Please tell me you don't write such mystical and surprising code in real life?